# "[mcve]" should magic-link to "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" help page

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks, minimal-reproducible-example

Good quality code examples are the bedrock of Stack Overflow and I'd like to make linking to the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help page even easier.

Please can we add a [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) so that I can type a comment:

> We can help you more easily if you include an [mcve].

and get:

> We can help you more easily if you include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I would also be OK with `[help/mcve]` as an alternative that better matches the existing `[help/dont-ask]`.

Comment: [It's now "MCVE" again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226439), both in the URL and in the title, so I guess it should be `[mcve]` => `[minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve)` now.

Comment: This question needs some more love. [I'm getting fed up of typing all this in myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006793/jquery-table-increment) a "magic link will make life much easier.

Comment: Worth noting you can use browser addons such as [Clippings](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clippings/?src=search) for saving messages for easy pasting later. So you can save your full explanation to the user that includes the MCVE link and just paste as you need with a right click.

Comment: Wish I could offer a bounty for this, 4 months and no answer... I could use that magic link.

Comment: If you ever implement this, please add it to [pt.so], as we do have this page there as well.

Comment: Now that the customary 6 to 8 weeks have passed several times, could someone actually take the 5 minutes required to implement this feature? ;-)

Comment: Surely the newer post should be closed as a duplicate of this question, as opposed to the other way round? I see 4 close votes on this one already.

Comment: @Luke: No, because the newer question has more useful content.

Comment: @Luke I'm happy just as long as it gets implemented somehow!