# Make Help Center Magic Link Anchor Text More Unique and Descriptive

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks, magic-links

Users are currently able to use ["magic" (shorthand) Markdown links in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), which are expanded into full urls with anchor text on submission. Unfortunately, the anchor text on many of these magic links are the same, and aren't very descriptive; many of them all say "help center", even though they point to different pages.

[Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261292/can-i-ask-question-like-how-does-stack-exchange-do-this#comment46715_261296):

[image: Screenshot]

In the 2<sup>nd</sup> comment that says:

> Please read [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [How to Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

The first "help center" link points to the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page, while the second "help center" link points to the [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page, and yet their anchor text is the same, and **this is confusing and awkward to read.**

I tested this out with other magic links, as demonstrated in the 3<sup>rd</sup> comment in the screenshot, and the following magic links (which go to different help center pages) all have "help center" as their anchor text:

1. `[help]`: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
2. `[help/on-topic]`: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
3. `[help/dont-ask]`: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
4. `[help/behavior]`: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)
5. `[meta-help]`: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

### Please Make Magic Link Anchor Text Unique and Descriptive

I think the magic links I pointed out above would be more useful and less confusing if they **each had their anchor text match the titles of the pages that they point to**, or at least use more descriptive, unique text, like the following:

1. `[help]`: "Help Center"
2. `[help/on-topic]`: "On-Topic"
3. `[help/dont-ask]`: "Off-Topic" or "Don't Ask"
4. `[help/behavior]`: "Expected Behavior" or "Rules of Conduct"
5. `[meta-help]`: "What is Meta?"

### Examples

This is how it currently looks again:

> Please read [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [How to Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Here is an example of what my comment above would look like using the full titles of the pages as anchor text:

> Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [How to Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

and this is what it would look like using the shorter anchor text:

> Please read [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [How to Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

### How Will This Affect Existing Comments?

I was thinking about how this would affect existing comments that were written with the current anchor text in mind. Take, for example, a comment like this that pointed to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Please read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

This comment makes sense the way it is, but with the changes that I proposed, it would look like

> Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

or

> Please read the [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

both of which are just as awkward as the current

> Please read [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

#### We Can Live with This

I think this is OK though, and here's why: **Help Center magic links are used in comments to help educate newbie users on how to use the site.** Once a newbie user has read the linked pages (assuming they read them at all once they're pointed to them), **then those older comments aren't needed anymore anyways.** They don't help future users find the answers that they're looking for.

So if old comments using magic links become awkward like

> Please read the [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

then **that's OK, because they've already served their purpose.**

Comment: I'm glad you posted this, as I didn't know there was a shorthand way to create the on-topic and don't-ask links, although I wholeheartedly agree that the text should be unique and descriptive

Comment: And, of course, when fixing this you can quickly this this one too: [Add a magic link to point to the “minimal working example” (MCVE) help page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258870/add-a-magic-link-to-point-to-the-minimal-working-example-mcve-help-page)

Comment: Wait, I...how did you even discover these?

Comment: Yes, yes, and pretty much **yes!** `[help/us/help/them/better]`

Comment: @DavidThomas: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183788/is-there-any-magic-link-like-faq-to-use-in-comments-for-the-page-listing-the-t

Comment: As the quick and ample comments and votes on [my recent question here on the same subject showed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305847/suggestion-for-distinguished-link-text-of-help-help-on-topic-help-dont-as/305928#305928): there's a lot of support for this feature, and hopefully it is trivial to implement. I'd greatly encourage the SO-team, provided they have some time on their hands (ugh), to implement this.

Comment: A potential solution: [Extend comment magic links syntax to allow arbitrary link text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261753)