# Suggestion for distinguished link text of [help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], etc

Tags: feature-request, help-improvement, magic-links

These currently [render as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522794/need-a-xslt-logic-to-parse-xml-type-data#comment52907755_32522794):

[image]

It is not very useful, while they do point to different pages. May I suggest different link texts, or the option in the `[...]` syntax to add a link text, like `[help/on-topic|On Topic]`?

It is just an idea. I know you guys are busy enough, but I like those shortcuts and am starting to memorize them. Some, like `[ask]` and `[mcve]`, which do change the link text, I have found extremely useful.

Comment: OK, the advanced link stuff doesn't work in comments (take up too many characters & don't work with the short cuts).

Comment: @BSMP, you mean the full syntax, like `[this is the title](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)`? Because what I am after is the brevity of the [tag:short-links].

Comment: A similar, though from my reading not quite the same, request on MSE: [Extend comment “magic links” syntax to allow arbitrary link text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261753/extend-comment-magic-links-syntax-to-allow-arbitrary-link-text) (Though the implementing of that one would give you a way to handle this issue.)

Comment: Personally I've rarely, if ever, had the desire to put multiple links to the help center in a single comment. Usually there's one main problem with the question, which I point out and link to the relevant section of the help center (with just a "See the [help center](http://this-is-a-link.example.com/)"). Taking the comment you referenced as example - that doesn't seem particularly useful to me - I can imagine someone thinking "Yes I am" and "What about them?". Point out specific problems if you want questions to be fixed and other users to get a better understanding of what's not appropriate.

Comment: @Dukeling, even in that scenario, _"see the help center"_ is less clear than _"see Questions you can ask"_ or _"Questions you should not ask"_. Besides, they already do this for `[ask]`: [ask] and `[mcve]`: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (didn't work on meta, but works on SO). Why stop there?

Comment: Use a browser [extension](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and make your own..I do.

Comment: @Paulie_D, sure, that's always an option.

Comment: Could you clarify this by showing the markup you used to generate your comment?

Comment: @jpmc26, what does _this_ refer to? ;). My OP, or a comment in the thread?

Comment: @jpmc26, I meant that typing [mcve] leaves it as _[mcve]_ on Meta (this is the actual code typed). The actual mcve link with link-text in [that comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305847/suggestion-for-distinguished-link-text-of-help-help-on-topic-help-dont-as#comment246046_305847) was made by hand using the uncannily unmemorizable and untypable `[link text](link reference)` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please, this would help immensely.

I'd propose the following syntax, resembling the usual links:

- `[help/dont-ask]` -> "*[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)*"
- `… [in the help](help/dont-ask)` → "*… [in the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)*"

The default text should be the title of the linked page.

But moreover I'd like to see this work for *all* help pages, not some unknown set of selected "frequently visited". `[help/self-answer]` or `[help/mcve]` (as in the URL) should *just work*. I don't want to look up the syntax in the [comment editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), I just want to c&p the URL path.

Comment: Thanks for the supportive response, apparently [I wasn't the first to think of this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261301/make-help-center-magic-link-anchor-text-more-unique-and-descriptive), let's upvote that other question as much as we can :).