# Feature request: specific anchor text for shortcuts in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, short-links

Shorthands like `[help/on-topic]` are very practical for writing comments quickly.

Unfortunately, using for instance the shorthand `[help/on-topic]` will result in a link to  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic but with the text "help center", same as for `[help/dont-ask]`. I'd like to have the title of the page (in this case "What topics can I ask about here?") as anchor text for shortcuts.

Comment: Or at least add custom anchor text. For example: \[help/on-topic][See what is on topic]

Comment: Custom text is possible with `[See what is on topic](/help/on-topic)` on main.

Comment: Related, if not dupe: [Make Help Center Magic Link Anchor Text More Unique and Descriptive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261301/215552)

Comment: @RocketNikita exactly, that would also be a good solution!

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks! I didn't know that

Comment: @HereticMonkey dupe, I would say, thanks for pointing out!