# Can we have [mcve] expand to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in comments, please

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, magic-links

Working through the review queue, I am finding it very common to need to refer new users who's questions are being close-voted to [the Minimal Complete Verifiable Example document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).    It would be a boon to have a shortcut for that link, automatically translating `[mcve]` (brackets included) to the 
equivalent of typing `[Minimal Complete Verifiable Example documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)`

Related MSE post: [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/200235)

Comment: MCVE is pretty regrettable, SSCCE was the mainstream term before StackExchange wrote the help center page.  With a very good [web site](http://sscce.org/) that explains what it means.  Blindly translating it is a problem, MCVE is ambiguous.  Mainstreet Credit Verification Engine is pretty popular.  Although we probably don't have to worry about programmers asking about Multimedia Collaborative Virtual Environments or Milk for Cheese Value Equivalent :)

Comment: @HansPassant: Sometimes, Silly Children Can't Educate :(

Comment: @HansPassant are you seriously suggesting that because MCVE is an acronym that might mean something else somewhere else, that would be a reason not to provide it as a shortcut for typing "[ Minimal Complete Verifiable Example ] `(` http`:`//stackoverflow.com/mvce `)`" in a comment?  This isn't "blind translation", this is translation of a very specific code in a very specific circumstance.   Find me one example of a comment in StackOverflow where someone typed [ mcve ] and didn't mean what I prosed it to shortcut to and ... I'll be danged thats for sure.

Comment: Yes I'm serious, credit card processing is a common programming task.  Of course I can't give you an example, there are entirely too many MCVE search hits.  In general, silently altering typed text is rather evil and universally despised.  Best way to help somebody is by not using jargon.

Comment: @HansPassant The shortcut being proposed is not MCVE.  It is `[mcve]` - with square brackets, in line with all the other magic shortcuts to the help centre... I don't think that shortcutting `[mcve]` can be argued to be more evil than shortcutting `[help]`, which is already there !

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to make that a bit more obvious.

Comment: Meanwhile, a workaround is to add this very question (or [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258870/mcve-should-magic-link-to-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example-help-p?lq=1)) to your favorites, and consult it each time you want to insert the link. Very tedious.

Comment: Unless/until this is implemented, you can always use something like PhraseExpress or AutoHotkey.

Comment: I wish I could just keep up-voting this. I find myself typing this a LOT, so much so that I keep Notepad open with a full comment that I can just copy in...

Comment: @Barry the best thing to do is supply an answer to this question stating your position on it (affirmative) and the rationale why.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294654/what-are-the-acceptable-expected-kinds-of-answers-for-feature-request-question/294657#294657 to confirm that this is "the best thing to do".

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]? Wooo!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This works now (only on Stack Overflow). The link text is "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" (which matches the title of https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [test at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119422/deleting-record-stores-of-one-app-using-another-app-in-j2me/14121998#comment50871326_14121998): passed! Test at MSO: [mcve]... fails as expected

Comment: Don't forget to update [Markdown editing help / comment formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @Mogsdad I have, at the same time I made this change. You're just looking at the wrong one. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @balpha how does it work exactly? I find myself referencing a good number of questions per day to the MCVE documentation. I wonder if it would be worth while to have a more relevant call to action to the doc when certain users are asking a question. These users could be: new users, users under a certain amount of reputation, users whose questions have been closed due to MCVE reasons in the past... etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: The link target is `http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve` - I think it would be better without explicit protocol as `//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve`, or (better) just `/help/mcve` (as I normally write, by hand) so as not to annoyingly downgrade HTTPS to HTTP for no good reason.  Saves a few valuable bytes, too.  :-)

Comment: Late to the party here, but isn't is useful to include it in the question body or some other place that new users will see / read it before they write the question? (maybe even something similar to [github issue templates](https://blog.github.com/2016-02-17-issue-and-pull-request-templates/))

Answer (score 68):

It would be better to have [mcve] auto-convert to `[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)` spelled out, since user Hans has pointed out that there is apparently some confusion, and esoteric acronyms aren't as helpful to people as words, anyway.

I didn't know what MCVE or SSCCE stand for before I came here (I still don't know what SSCCE stands for, actually), and I sometimes even mess up the order of the acronym... so I wouldn't expect newcomers (ostensibly the group this feature would benefit) to know, either.

Comment: It stands for [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: And before that, there was [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), which is still worth reading.

Comment: I have a trivial shell script that generates two lines of output: `MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))`, which produces MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
when not escaped.  It isn't hard to use it when I need it. This is not intended to dismiss the suggestion; it is simply an observation that it is not hard to make it easy for yourself even without help from SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler a shell script to generate a hard-coded string?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Yes; it's easy for me to run (it's called `sscce` since it pre-dates the MCVE page).  I can copy'n'paste (and if put the effort into it, I could almost certainly have the command copy into the copy'n'paste buffer, but that would be less portable).  It isn't exciting; it is effective for me.  It actually contains two `echo` commands, though it could be written with a here-document and `cat` instead.  Anyway, how else would you write it?  A C program would be overkill.  An alias would be silly; I don't use it enough to warrant it being an alias.

Comment: I would just have a line in my `stuff.txt` that stays open in Notepad++, but I don't spend that much time in the shell. To each their own, I'm sure.

Comment: What's Notepad++?  :D  Yes, each to their own.