# What are the acceptable/expected kinds of answers for "feature request" questions?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm not clear whether appropriate answers for "feature requests" include "I would like this because" answers?

A feature request is often of the form "Can we have this feature?".  In which case, it appears to be addressed to someone who can decide the answer (yes or no).   That in turn seems to make discussion of the merits not actually an answer, which results in long comments discussions.

Is this what we want, or is it actually most appropriate for opinions about whether the feature should be accepted or not (with accompanying rationale) to be given as answers?

Comment: Shouldn't we have a StackOverflow Meta Meta for these sorts of questions? ;-)

Comment: @MichalCharemza That's just asking for an infinite recursion of Meta's

Comment: @Degustaf yeah and we don't want that because it might cause a Stack Overflow

Comment: :P nice one. puns though....

Comment: @Degustaf We could go the Smalltalk way and have a Meta-Meta-Stack-Exchange (whose meta site is itself Meta Stack Exchange)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Answering a feature request just gives the community an opportunity to voice their support for either your version of the proposal or your current take on whether or not it is desirable.

Answers are **far** more desirable than comments, because they allow that position to be vetted by the community and answers have a staying power that comments will never have.

So, in some ways, yes a feature-request is similar to a discussion. The whole idea of feature requests is to give the community a place to discuss and propose features and I think it makes sense to do that.

The main difference is in the post itself. Voting on feature requests indicate agreement with the feature in question. Voting on answers tends to be no different than any other place, and indicate the usefulness and contribution of the answer. Voting on answers to feature requests do tend to indicate agreement with the point of view put forward, but that is how most of meta works anyway.

tldr; Please, feel free to answer feature requests with a point of view. It will just add to the discourse which is advantageous to the whole community.

Comment: Completely agree. Sometimes [tag:feature-request] only explains situations and expected result, but no concrete implementation. Answer can be used to propose the implementation of the idea, or temporary workaround (usually related to userscript).

Comment: Very significantly (in my opinion), raising points of view in (separate) answers allows those to be discussed separately (in each answer's comments) as opposed to the mess which is all together (in the question's comments).