# Add keyboard shortcuts to review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, keyboard-shortcuts

Lot of times when clicking on <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> in Low Quality Posts review I just vote with "*No comment needed*" but I still have to click twice using mouse (second time is <kbd>Delete</kbd> button).

It would be much more comfortable if I could use <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of clicking on <kbd>Delete</kbd> button.

Second thing would be using (for example) arrows for changing delete vote reasons.

And the third *<kbd>L</kbd>ooks okay*, *Recommend <kbd>D</kbd>eletion*, <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to skip.

I would like to use <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of 3 clicks of the mouse.

Or at least *click <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd>*, (select comment),<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The same thing could work for <kbd>Vote Close</kbd> and so on.

Comment: I don't know that I would like anything that makes it easier for robo-reviewers to be... robotic.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If I'm a professional robo-reviewer, I already have a script to push the buttons for me. If someone can go through the queue pressing "D" robotically, there's a much higher chance that they'll fail a review audit if they don't have the time to think about whether they're facing and audit.

Comment: @Undo I was more targeting amateur robo-reviewers, but I get what you mean ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan won't it make robo-reviewer detection easier? The time between reviews will get shorter... Anyway you're saying not to implement user comfort feature because of potential abuse, although it can be scripted more efficiently right now....

Comment: I don't know how robo-reviewers are detected now, if at all. And I'm not saying to not implement it. In fact, I upvoted the feature-request :). I'm just bringing up a potential drawback to adding these shortcuts. It might be something to address in your feature request to allay concerns others may have.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Robo-reviewers are at present chiefly detected through audits, and occasionally detected through manual diamond review, statistical methods, or even fellow reviewer suspicion: we just had a whole batch of reviewers given time off a few days ago because someone noticed a lot of a particular user's suggestions had been wrongly approved. Audits and statistics will not be affected negatively by the suggestion and may get slightly more precise; manual review will be unaffected.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan according to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294657/1149736) you should make an answer from your comment so we would see what community thinks :)

Comment: Some members don't bother with the review queues because of the lack of keyboard shortcuts. I think SO could be missing out on a good chunk of the community that would be good reviewers but couldn't be bothered with the mouse, here.

Answer (score -1):

My first reaction to this was concern over robo-reviewers, who already spend too little time on each review. If we make it easier/faster for them to gain their internet points, we risk having more problems with hastily accepted suggested edits, bad questions, etc..

Now, it may be that this stereotypical robo-reviewer will simply get banned faster as the audits will be introduced more often (if there are a set number of audits per number of reviews), so that risk may be mitigated.

Another mitigating factor is the rate-limiting features of the review queues. Since you can only do X number of reviews per time period, no one's going to get any more points than they would have otherwise... They'll just run out of reviews faster.

Anyway, I've written this answer to raise the concern of making things easier for robo-reviewers, so vote on whether than is indeed a pressing concern, or not.