# Meta-Meta-Stack Overflow - When should I answer or comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, meta

I am trying to become more active on Meta and one thing I am unsure of is when I should answer a question, and when I should simply comment.

In the case of a discussion, and I have something more to say, I don't know which is right. I feel that either option allows me to contribute what I want to (unless I am fueled up and exceed the character limit of a comment). On the flip side, a discussion doesn't always *have* a single answer, so what should be posted?

For feature requests, and as well as discussions, I know I can vote to signify whether or not I agree with the topic. Again, I can comment about something small that I might have in addition to or against said feature request. Should I as a user, though, answer a feature request? I am not a moderator or an Stack Overflow developer, I cannot make feature requests happen, and so I cannot really give an answer to the request, but I may have more than 600 characters of opinion on the topic.

I have not found anything on this topic yet, and I have not been around Meta long enough to know what the general course of action is. Do we have guidelines on what should be answers and what should be comments on Meta? Can someone help clarify the difference, so that I (and others) can become better participants here?

Comment: Well for starters, it is generally not the best idea to [post an answer that is less substantial than the majority of comments already on the question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EBsyY.png).

Comment: Of course, and I have read the help center, but I feel that it is geared towards Stack Overflow itself. While the quality rules still apply, I guess I'm referring more to the content of an answer, and what qualifies an answer to a discussion, or feature request.

Comment: The Q+A format is a pretty abysmal way to have a [discussion].  Even if somebody posts an answer, the interesting back-and-forth is still conducted in the comments on that post.  There, just another two-bit opinion.

Comment: Concerning feature requests: don't worry about not being in a position to make it happen. If you have an opinion and an argument to support it, post an answer (unless your point was already made in existing answers). The road of feature requests to fulfillment is long, and the discussion within community is the first step.

Comment: Related: [What are the acceptable/expected kinds of answers for “feature request” questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294654/1026459)

Comment: I really want to ask a question about if I should answer or comment on meta-meta-stackoverflow posts when I have an opinion.

Comment: @James: For that, I'm afraid you'll have to ask on Quora. :P

Comment: something "witty"

Comment: This question should be in Meta-Meta Stack Exchange...

Comment: @BoltClock, true, but [important messages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297137/960757) were deleted from that thread too. How can we prepare for a bottle invasion now?

Comment: I have a really low rank on S/O because I only post questions after searching diligently for dupes, on S/O or elsewhere. So the questions I ask tend to be corner-cases. Likewise I ignore questions that I know are dupes, though sometimes I help people in comments if they seem befuddled in good faith. So .. my $.02 - add something to say if it's substantive and non-duplicative; otherwise be grateful for those who have taken the time to answer already.

Answer (score 93):

### Observations regarding appropriate participation in meta discussions

- If you have something worth saying about the topic of the discussion, **post an answer.**
- If you have something worth saying about the post that raises the discussion (but does not actually contribute to the discussion itself at all), then **post a comment** on the question. Expect that it may be deleted at any time.
- If you have something "witty" to say, **post a comment** on the question. Expect that it might get massively upvoted and derail any further discussion.
- If you have a counterpoint to an existing answer, **post your own answer.**
- If you have a procedural point to make regarding an existing answer, **post a comment on that answer.**
- If you have an "amusing" "meme" "image" that is in some way "relevant", **post an answer.**

Comment: Thank you for mixing in humor among serious comments. I understand that the rules on MSO are little more loose (i.e. memes in answers aren't too frowned upon) but sometimes I will have an opinion to voice and I want it to be done properly, and sometimes I'm not sure what course of action to take. This, however, cleared it up for me pretty well.

Comment: @McAdam331 note that Meta votes are different - expect and not worry about massive downvotes on answers if people disagree, especially do not delete answer just due to downvotes (assuming it is valid opinion, and not something turned out to be misunderstanding/misinformation). It is actually nice to have opposite opinions in discussion.

Comment: I second @AlexeiLevenkov opinion. My [latest question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-stack-overflow) on MSO have been voted down to -6 before raising up to +70 and got "featured". Besides, there is not rep on MSO so again, *don't worry about massive downvotes*.

Comment: Here's [an example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29137/244519) of the last bullet point.

Comment: As a fairly new SO participant, and this is good, concise relevant information. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean Alexei, and I agree 100%. I have had questions over 100+ on Meta and also scored below 20 on some. You're right, an opposing opinion can be just as helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Shog has already taken care of most things but there's a bit of the question I think needs a specific answer:

> Should I as a user, though, answer a feature request? I am not a moderator or an Stack Overflow developer, I cannot make feature requests happen, and so I cannot really give an answer to the request, but I may have more than 600 characters of opinion on the topic.

If you have something substantial to say about the feature request, then by all means *you should answer*. I typically will start my answers with "I [support/do not support] this proposal because..." It is clear I'm only talking for myself, not for the devs or the mods.

You probably already know that some proposals are unacceptable because they go against a basic principle of how SO operates. For instance, any proposal that would entail removing voting anonymity is dead in the water. You don't need to be a dev to know this. You can write up an answer that explains why the proposal would harm vote anonymity, etc. Then a dev or a moderator can just add the `status-declined` tag to the question. You've saved them time.

Moreover, you may have arguments that the devs or the moderators have not considered. Or you may be expressing the same argument more skillfully or in a way that just happens to be more digestible by the OP. Ultimately, your answer may be more persuasive to the OP than those of the devs or mods.

In some cases, having a "regular" user answer the OP instead of someone who is perceived to be a representative of "the authority" *can* help convey the fact that it's not just the way it is because the mods say so: that's what other users want too.

Comment: Where were you? Had you answered earlier, Shog wouldn't have had to go through the trouble.