# Lower threshold for newbie comments on Meta

Tags: feature-request

I see an explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), why a 50-reputation-points threshold is maintained on Stack Overflow. However, there is a big difference between Stack Overflow and Meta.

Stack Overflow discusses user questions about "universe", and Meta - questions about the portal. These questions in particular reflect, how comfortable newbie feel themselves here. Opinions of all user categories must be counted if we want to grow the Stack Exchange audience. But currently newbies have no say on Meta, they can't support other newbies asking to adjust certain practices to fit specific newbie needs, because of the artificially high comments threshold.

As a result, comments on Meta in practice represent opinion of small minority of high rep users. While Stack Exchange claims its main principle be based on democracy, blocking the entire newbie population from comments looks as far from democracy as it takes. It looks like dictatorship of small majority resulting in many discussions don't reflect public opinion.

I ask to lower threshold for Meta comments to 20.

Comment: Users with less than 50 rep can ask questions (as you've demonstrated) and add answers. Making it out like they have no representation due to a lack of commenting is a bit of a stretch...

Comment: Its not a stretch at all. I posted suggestions on Meta about certain policies, and because only high rep can comment, they simply deleted my questions about policies claiming they're "unclear" or without any justification, so no-one can read the discussion. If other newbies had representation, the outcome would be much different.

Comment: If they are unclear why didn't you edit them to make them clear? Just link to one if your deleted questions if you like.

Comment: Why there is such aggressive attempt to delete this request without any discussion on its face?

Comment: I feel privileged to be "high rep" now, when I can't even edit on Meta... Seriously, though, even if we lowered the comment limit on Meta, your questions can _still_ be closed in _exactly_ the same way as today, they can _still_ be deleted, and no amount of commenting is going to change that. And you're making it out like the Meta regulars are the bad guys, like _we're_ the only ones doing wrong. Perhaps you're legitimately not posing clear questions on occasion? (Just because they're clear to you doesn't mean they are to everyone.)

Comment: One post, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328105/, to which [you're presumably referring](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328279/lower-threshold-for-newbie-comments-on-meta#comment368439_328279) has no end of comments from you, none of which actually address the critiques in the other comments. (And nor do your edits, which are the correct way to address those anyways.)

Comment: How will lowering the reputation needed to comment on meta solve this problem you are having? If a question is deleted because it is unclear generally only the person who posted it would be able to fix it.

Comment: _"Why there is such aggressive attempt to delete this request without any discussion on its face?"_ As far as I'm aware, people can't vote to delete your question until it's closed. I can't see if there are votes for that on here or not, though I don't see what this would be closed as myself. Your question _is_ being downvoted, but that is in no way the same thing.

Comment: As of this moment, there are no votes for closure here.

Comment: You may want to learn a bit more about how Stack Overflow works before "aggressively" assigning malicious intent on users with "high rep".

Comment: @Josh Yes I was the only one defending my suggestion in the linked thread because the entire newbie population affected by that suggestion was blocked from commenting. That is very good illustration to my above request.

Comment: "Newbies" who are concerned about a Meta topic [can post answers with their opinions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297069/), and vote on other answers. Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111910/

Comment: Note that 50 rep is not that much. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/215552 for many tips on how to gain reputation.

Comment: @Josh How would one post an answer on a feature request that doesn't have a question, but rather a suggestion to improve the site policies? Any such "answer" would be immediately set for review and shortly deleted, as there was no question posted, but a feature request. Look even now, why folks keep down-voting my request without any explanation? What can be wrong with asking to allow all community members to be equally represented at least when discussing policies that affect everyone?

Comment: Why do you assume that your posts will be deleted?  Comments are _much_ more likely to be deleted than posts.

Comment: @sambul35 An answer to a feature request would explain why you feel it would, or would not, make a good feature, and why, like the answer posted below to your feature request.  Such answers aren't just deleted, I don't know why you'd think they would be.

Comment: How much more explanation in comments do you want then? We have provided feedback for you here and now. That it is not the feedback you want to hear  is not our fault, is it? I also want to make you aware that your assumption of over representation by a few high reps is at best [mis-guided](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/514565)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I dropped the request, since an answer can be posted instead of comments, which I didn't know in case of a feature request.

Comment: Which meta are you talking about? Meta Stack Exchange? Meta Stack Overflow? Both?

Comment: *"blocking the entire newbie population from comments looks as far from democracy as it takes. It looks like dictatorship"* In a lot of democracies (all?), you can't vote until you reach a specific age.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a relatively low-rep Meta regular, I just don't see the problem you're talking about.

I've seen plenty of instances of users with less than 50 rep chipping in on a question they didn't create, in the form of *posting an answer with their opinions on the matter.* Admittedly, sometimes these posts are just comments and don't belong in the answer section, but that happens on Stack Overflow as well as here.

But several times I have seen instances of users with less than 50 rep posting answers that are *good,* well thought out, and well received. They're able to do this without commenting on the post at all.

Even if you don't post an answer with your opinion, you can still weigh in on posts by upvoting. If you don't have the 15 rep for that, then answering with your opinion on the matter will be all you've got until you get that 10 or less rep you need. (You need 5 rep to hit Meta, anyway.)

Looking at why you want this, it won't help like you seem to think it will. From one of your comments:

> I posted suggestions on Meta about certain policies, and because only high rep can comment, they simply deleted my questions about policies claiming they're "unclear" or without any justification, so no-one can read the discussion. If other newbies had representation, the outcome would be much different.

No, the outcome *wouldn't* have been different, I can almost guarantee that. The 3k+ rep users that closed your question *still* would have been able to close it, regardless of the comments, and the 10k+ users that voted to delete your question still would have been able to vote to delete it. That would not have been changed at all by users with less than 50 rep weighing in in the comments.

> How would one post an answer on a feature request that doesn't have a question, but rather a suggestion to improve the site policies?

This came up in the comments as well, and, as you can see by the answers to this very question, an answer posted that explains why someone feels a feature request is good or bad, explains it, and if necessary gives evidence is perfectly acceptable for these questions.

In fact, they can help to convince other users to support or help reject the change. If the OP's opinion is changed by such an answer, they can accept said answer to show what they think on the matter.

In some cases, an answer to a feature-request can even be pointing out how the existing tools already meet the OP's needs or, in some cases, where to find what they're looking for already implemented in the system.

Comment: I think now you guys are correct on these points, if such answers to feature requests are allowed instead of comments. So I drop my above request. :) Is there a way to drop it formally?

Comment: They indeed are. I've answered my share of feature requests with opinions of why they should or shouldn't be implemented. It's answers like these, especially if you have data to back it up, that can help convince other people for or against the feature and help prove why it would or would not be a good idea.

Comment: As for dropping it formally, not really. You could select one of our answers as "accepted" to show your opinion has been swayed, but you can't delete because of our answers. Though leaving this here for a future user looking to suggest the same is always a good idea.

Answer (score 12):

I am opposed to this feature request because **comments are not important for meta participation.  Questions and answers are much more important for meta participation, which you already have access to**.  If there is a truly important comment, it should exist as an answer instead.  Lowering the reputation limit for meta comments would just encourage more overuse of comments.

> While SE claims its main principle be based on democracy, blocking the entire newbie population from comments looks as far from democracy as it takes.

Meta does not prevent newbies from participating.  The only barrier to entry for meta participation is the minimum 5 reputation to prevent mass spamming of meta.  That's lower than every other earned privilege.  And new users posting here on meta do get the attention they deserve from meta frequenters.  If there is under-representation of low rep users, it's because many don't care enough to visit meta and (up)vote posts that express their opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are not intended for extended discussion nor are they meant as a venue for answers to be placed.

The answer feature for answers is where answers go. Once an answer is posted, the poster may comment on that answer if there needs to be any other clarifying points or responses made to other users.

If changing the threshold meant that more answers would come in the format of comments, then that would not be desirable.

Anyone may answer a question (provided they are not answer banned). Thus, everyone has a voice.