# What should I do about a user that I'm trying to help and is calling me stupid

Tags: discussion

I saw a question that was closed because it was too broad. I also flagged the question, because I also think it is too broad a question. But the user didn't understand why his question was closed so I tried to help him understand why his question was closed.
I sent him a link on how to ask a good question, and added some explanation to it. But then he started calling me crazy and stupid and that I was 'out of my mind'. I simply told him he shouldn't have included links with code and instead just pasted the code in the question. 
I flagged 2 of his comment as rude but he keeps going with what is in my opinion unacceptable behavior on this site.
So what should I do about it? Is there any way to flag the user if he keeps sending rude comments? Or just flag the individual comments?

Comment: Your comments might be seen as too terse, ie not enough details. Your "goodbye" comment is a bit abrasive, then you appear to contradict that comment by adding more responses. When I comment on a poor question I try to give more details plus links to a Stackoverflow help page in my first comment.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I agree with you about that goodbye comment, but I sent him a link: how to ask a good question, also I gave him advice how he could make his question better in the future. So in my opinion I gave enough details to the specific user.

Comment: You might consider using the [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to deliver canned responses for (new) users. And after that disengage if you didn't detect enough cooperation at the other side.

Comment: @Bas Agreed that you gave the information. My point is that I try and put more detail into my first response.

Comment: That escalated very fast - too fast for my taste. Looking at OP Mark's list of rather bad questions, is it possible he is mistaking Stack Overflow for Laravel Support? See **Things of Interest** near the bottom of [this introduction](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/guidelines-for-posting-on-laracastscom) for Laravel devs.

Comment: Whilst the OP's past questions may not be particularly fantastic, his previous comments to other users were polite and expressed gratitude upon receiving help....until he bumped into you, and I can see why. Your comments would rub me up the wrong way. You don't need to complete every comment with an exclamation mark it just comes across as abrasive. There are ways to communicate the errors of a new user's ways to set them on the right track, yours is not the way.

Comment: You should stop trying to help them.

Comment: Your question if a good question and Jon Skeet has given the canonical answer. But your own comments were rude and not constructive. I'm sorry, but I think OP was rude with you only because you had been first with him.

Comment: @Kev I flagged/deleted a couple of his comments where he started to be rude immediately, so you didn't see al of his comments. I agree that I should have reacted differently at some point!.

Comment: @samgak: no, you should *help* them to get the help they ask.

Comment: @Jongware: Honestly, _why_? Their need for help is their own responsibility, not ours.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "help me with this." My suggested response: "see the Help for tips on how to ask." Yours cannot seriously be "wot you mean? go away!" Pointing new users to the Help can't ever hurt.

Comment: @Jongware: I didn't say it should be! What I'm saying is that I disagree with the assertion that we "should" help them to get the help they ask. It's nice of us to do so and sometimes I do too, but sometimes I just move on to the next question because the OP should have read the Help material without being prompted to. That was their responsibility, before posting. In fact they _were_ prompted to, many times, upon registering...

Comment: @Lightness: agree to disagree. In fact, I wholly agree that your method is highly preferable over engaging a new user into a *discussion* on why his question is so bad.

Comment: @Jongware: Indeed :)

Comment: It is always good to train oneself to see ones own ego or self showing up when challenged by a question or comment that you do not think forwards the support session.  Patience is valuable and keeping in focus how the user can be best assisted. People does not always behave the way you would want them to, may not have read and understood prerequisites, may be in a bad mood, may not come across as clever. And still need not be a valid reason for letting ones own temper kick in.

Comment: I dont see why this is actually that well received of a question. It's quite obvious that if there's something wrong with a comment, you flag it. Let the moderators judge what they'll do with it if it gets out of hand. Also about people saying people being taught a lesson, I would say that theres nothing we can do about it. If the user does **a lot** of stuff against the rules, I have faith that the moderators will handle this. What else do you want to do? **TL:DR Just flag it. Have faith that this will be handled the right way by moderators.**

Comment: You should remove the link to the now deleted question @Bas.

Comment: I never did understand these "I need your help, but I'm going to make it unnecessarily hard for you to actually help me" questions. I wonder if part of it is a lack of confidence in getting an answer. If you don't believe you will actually get an answer, you don't want to "waste" too much effort posting the question. Of course, it then becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: This sure seems relevant - https://xkcd.com/386/ - if someone doesn't want help and is arguing, don't waste your time. Just... walk away. It's that easy in theory, but impossibly hard sometimes to do.

Comment: The user's page now shows _"Last seen Oct 29 '15 at 17:51"_. I'm not sure if I should be happy or not that he is gone, it feels mixed. Guess not everyone can be taught to ask a question meaningfully..

Comment: @Bas - I would ask them to put better info without making it sound like I am admonishing them. If they talk trash, then just ignore them. The more you talk to such people, the more they talk rubbish.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Flag the individual comments, and after a few good-faith attempts to explain what the user should do, leave the question alone - if only for your own sanity.

In this case, it looks like there's little hope for this user. Better to walk away than to let them spoil your day.

Comment: I too agree with this but don't you think that they should be taught a lesson too @jonskeet

Comment: @CoderNeji: I don't want to get in the retribution game. If the flags are upheld, the user could be banned for their behaviour - and the question is already deleted. What sort of "lesson" do you think needs to be taught beyond that?

Comment: @CoderNeji - I think Jon's approach is the most appropriate and also healthier for you. It is not a good idea to get into a sort of blood feud, you seek retribution, then he seeks retribution, and so on, somewhere it has to stop. So, it is better if it doesn't even start. At least you can say you walked away the better man :)

Comment: yeah. I know. After all he's JON SKEET... #respect

Comment: Just confirming that this is a sound approach and works well on SO. I recently tried to point out to a late answer consisting mostly of a link to github that it needed more detail, got a cheeky response, tried explaining again about SO trying to be a reference site, and when the answerer's comment became downright rude, I flagged it and left for a while. (Though I must admit I was tempted for a moment to stoop to his level... glad I didn't.) When I checked back a couple of hours later, the answer had been deleted. Whoever is working the flag queues seems to be prioritising well, kudos. :-)

Answer (score 104):

> So what should I do about it? Is there anyway to flag the user if he keeps sending rude comments? or this flag the individual comments?

Basically, what Jon says. Still ... let's go over *your* responses only.

> *What have you tried so far?*

Almost always unnecessary to ask. Close-vote as "Unclear what you are asking" is enough. Then ...

> *Your question is closed because it doesn't fit SO rules. If you don't like the rules go ahead and go somewhere else. Try the laravel forums.!*

Ouch. The question was already closed. There may have been a comment in between to which you responded this. It's still quite borderline.

> *also take a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's about how to ask a good question.*

Now that's actually a constructive comment and may have been mentioned earlier.

> *Yes that's the reason your question got closed!*

Try not to get drawn into a discussion. The OP may believe he **must** defend against **you**, just because you are the one replying all the time.

> *No it isn't clear to me! You should add more details like what you already tried. Show us some code. That way people wil likely help you if you show effort!*

Around here I got the feeling the discussion could easily go out of control. Exclamation marks?

> *I didn't see it because if you include that it should be included in the question. And the thing that you should do is not to provide a link with your code but paste the code in the question. So it's more clear. Also provide a short but complete example demonstrating your problem, so it's easier for people to help you!]*

Apart from the last line, this is a fairly reasonable comment.

> *i am sorry but you're reaction isn't acceptable, and I'm not going to try and help you. Goodbye*

... and this, and your next comments were not constructive at all.

Try to place yourself in the OP's position. Fairly new here: "Member for 38 days" and lacking the "Informed" badge, which strongly suggests he has not read anything the Help center has to offer.

His previous 7 questions were received badly: -4 and -1, and only 2 lonely up votes. Not much guidance from other users. He must be wondering what he is doing wrong, and why [is Stack Overflow either ignoring him, or plain mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953).

I suggest pointing *early* and *firm* but *polite* to the Help Center. There are shortcuts to do so for `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]`, `[help/behavior]` and `[meta-help]` (which all insert the plain text "help center").

Also note the distinct lack of exclamation marks in my post! (oops)

Comment: Is there a way to use `[help/mcve]`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: the list comes verbatim from the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).  Alas, [no](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294563/2564301).

Comment: I agree with all of Jongware's remarks. Given the curt comments, the "go away" and the numerous exclamation marks, I think the OP of this meta kind of provoked the insult. In other situations, if someone drops an insult out of the blue, then that's unacceptable behavior and should be flagged. As a rule of thumb, if you can manage to be perfectly polite to a confused beginner and explain to them where they went wrong, then great! If you can't be patient enough for that, possibly because the confused beginner is very dense or simply not listening, then just drop it and move on.

Comment: @Lundin: but keep in mind some of OP's comments were already removed before we got to see them. They were apparently provocative enough to be taken out immediately.

Comment: @Jongware Ah, that is true, I didn't consider that since the whole question was deleted anyhow.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that I should have reacted differently maybe, but like Jongware said 3 of his comments were already flagged/deleted were he started insulting me, when I said nothing wrong.

Answer (score -27):

On any forum, but *especially* on one that's visited by thousands of people *per second* around the world, I think it's most-important that you address the **question** that is being asked, and not the **human being** who is asking it.  Always bear in mind that you are not "speaking." You are *writing.*  The person will not "hear" any inflections of your voice, nor "see" any body-language.

What the person *will* see, maybe, is that "s/he is being castigated in a very public place."  (I started to paste an image of the painting, *The Scream,* here ...)  No, they won't let you hear them Scream, but they might Scream anyway.

No matter what you "intended," be *hyper-*sensitive to how it *might* come across.  And if you don't have a clear, informed, technical answer to the question being asked, simply let the thread drift on by.  Tact, and diplomacy, and sometimes restraint, are all key.

Comment: Ignoring bad posts is not an option. Still, just downvoting and close-voting/flagging is.

Comment: Oh, I don't agree at all.  :-)  (Speaking *generically, not personally(!)* here ...) "So 'you' think it's 'bad.'  Who cares what 'you' think?"  Let someone *else* be the person to say that, and hope that nobody will.  "Graciousness, diplomacy, and tact."  In addition, I do not *down*-vote anything.  I might "flag" a post to call a moderator's attention to it, and I will certainly *up*-vote notable answers now and then.  But, "being on the receiving end of negativity, of whatever form or intention ... *hurts like hell.*"

Comment: Seems you don't understand what moderation is for: It's for the next dozen guys as an indication whether it might be worth their time, not for the OP.

Comment: "Don't understand what moderation is for?"  :-)  That's kind of silly, now isn't it?  If the post is really *good,* in your opinion, then upvote it.  (A large positive number always stands out.)  But what good, really, is a downvote?  Maybe the person who's downvoting just doesn't understand the question or it rubs him/her the wrong way ... who knows.   Well, anyway, that's been my experience:  that posts with lots of upvotes are usually really good, and posts with lots of downvotes are often really not so bad.  (And if the post is "abusive," "anti-social," that's an entirely different flag.)

Comment: But that's the beauty of a great big forum:  thousands of people here, and "vote and act according to the dictates of your own conscience."  Thanks for the thoughts, and good day to you!  :-)

Comment: @Mike: we are all grown ups here (which is kinda nice if you happen to still be near the minimum allowed age - "[at least 13 years of age](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)") and there is no requirement to walk on our toes and pray not to offend anyone. But that is a far cry from *sensible* behavior, such as being curteous, respectful, or (indeed) curt, succinct, or brief. The latter ones may be mistaken as insulting by a hyper-sensitive reader, but *usually* no malice should be assumed.

Comment: The intention of down votes is not just to tell that the post is bad, but down votes should also be used to tell that an answer is incorrect. An answer might be on-topic and nicely written, but still 100% incorrect when it comes to the actual technical content. You should not flag that. By site design, the only moderation tool available against such incorrect answers is down votes. (And if you cast such a down vote and the poster then corrects the error, you should consider removing the down vote or even up vote.)

Comment: As for me, I have seen many posts and questions downvoted "without comment," and therefore when considering the post or the thread I usually just ignore the number completely.  If a post/thread has received a noticeable number of upvotes, I start there.  And this is simply how I use this metric.

Comment: Encouraging/Forcing comments on voting is a whole other debate. Which was had, repeatedly and then some, always leading to the same conclusion.

Comment: Mike, this isn't a forum.  It's a community-moderated Q&A site. That's not the same thing, so the rules aren't the same. Leaving garbage on the site isn't an option. It breeds vermin.

Comment: @MikeRobinson - I think you should take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/when-or-should-you-delete-your-incorrect-answer), and stop the bleeding.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't **attack** the user, but addressing their behavior can be very helpful, if done politely. When a user clearly doesn't understand how the site works, you're not doing them any favors by ignoring their behavior. Until they learn how to post good questions, they're far less likely to get good answers that help them with their problems.

Comment: Mike, you *really* need to stop referring to Stack Overflow as a forum, this is perhaps the 5th or 6th time I've seen one of your answers referring to Stack Overflow as a forum.

Comment: This answer isn't so bad to deserve so many downvotes! Also, SO is a forum, it's just not a forum forum.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).