# Bug with voting sidebar?

Tags: bug, voting, bookmarks

I was searching around on meta when I came across a [What should I do about a user that I'm trying to help and is calling me stupid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296913/what-should-i-do-about-a-user-that-im-trying-to-help-and-is-calling-me-stupid):

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

I noticed that you couldn't vote on the question. I found it strange, since the question was only asked yesterday. It seemed strange since there was no lock notice or anything either. So, I clicked where there were normally vote buttons, and favourite buttons, and it worked! Is this a bug? Could it be related to the new sticky voting thingermajiggers?

I'm running Safari 7.1.6 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) if that helps. :)

Comment: Maybe add your system/browser specs. Looks normal to me. Although, I, for some reason, don't get the new UI testing group interface anymore :(

Comment: This happened to me earlier today but I didn't look into it much.  Haven't noticed it since.

Comment: Could be a problem with outdated long-lived assets. Have you tried <s>turning it off and on again</s> clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Seems to me like the up/down images didn't load for some reason. Could have been on either end really -- maybe your browser hiccuped trying to load them from cache, or glitched trying to fetch them from the server, or the server failed to respond. In your screenshot the "favorite" star failed to load as well.

Comment: Even after refreshing the page, it still doesn't fix. I've cleared my website data, and it doesn't work *only* on that page...