# Is there a way to quickly redirect OP to help about "How to ask" or "Minimal, Verifiable and Complete" and prevent down vote?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I see that a large amount of questions are asked by users that have not read the basic help pages [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

So before answering, most people start by repeating to check those sections and edit the question first. Others do not bother commenting and down vote the question.

I saw [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294563/can-we-have-mcve-expand-to-http-stackoverflow-com-help-mcve-in-comments-ple) that mvce (and other magic links) can be used as a shortcut in comments to link to the help page, but wouldn't it be nice to have "something like a flag" indicating automatically to the OP that his question has not the correct formatting or the sufficient amount of information with links to pages that will help him improve his post ? 
Such flagging should maybe put the question on hold for some time to prevent people trying to answer it ? Maybe until the OP has edited it ?

Existing flags such as "should be closed..." or "very low quality..." does not apply for this kind of questions or are at least a bit extreme in many cases.

Such a flag could avoid people for repeating 100 times the same thing in comment, provide the OP with a direct link with "need-to-know" help pages and maybe prevent people to answer an incomplete or unclear question ...

Comment: We already have close votes which act like a flag to prevent the question from being answered if it needs improvement.

Comment: What's a PO? Do you mean OP?

Comment: This is what close voting is for.  It places the question on hold and it tells the OP what is wrong and links to relevant help files.

Comment: Then I think that close voting is not sufficiently used since in many situations questions remain open with a bunch of comments about basic edition

Comment: @steiner There are only so many people who can close vote and it normally takes 5 of them to close a question.  It only takes one person to ask a question.

Comment: It's a fair question but the reason it needs 5 close votes (or 1 Magic Close Vote from a gold badge holder) is people have to agree the question has pr0blems. I.e. just because one person does not understand a question does not mean it should be closed immediately. Also, sometimes receiving close votes makes the asker edit the question.

Comment: Of course you are both true. Thus my question was is there any less radical way but more automatic to orient the OP towards some help on edition ? I saw that @NathanOliver for example is often saying the same comments about edition. Aren't you tired of doing so ?

Comment: @steiner Kinda but you are missing the point.  One person should not be able to put the Q on hold unless it is a mod or they are using their dupe hammer.  Otherwise it requires community consensus as what is too broad in one persons view can be totally acceptable in another persons view.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok then. So the correct behavior is what ? down-vote or comment or both or nothing ? Receiving a down-vote encourage to go away, not really to edit and make a better question ...

Comment: IMHO if it looks salvageable then comment and close vote.  If its a home work dump maybe comment, close vote and down vote.  If it is straight up garbage down vote and close vote.  Also you can use the [Auto Review Comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to make commenting easier.

Answer (score 2):

> Such flagging should maybe put the question on hold for some time to prevent people trying to answer it ? Maybe until the OP has edited it ?

That's literally what voting to close does.

> Existing flags such as "should be closed..." or "very low quality..." does not apply for this kind of questions or are at least a bit extreme in many cases.

How does it not apply?  It does *exactly* what you're proposing your new flag do.